# Tikz: positioning library breaks path picture bounding box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, bounding-box

I try to create and order text boxes with tikz-nodes.  The nodes are ordered so far using the tikz `positioning` library.  Additionally, I try to have numbers on the background of the nodes by using `path picture`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\usepackage{environ}

\newlength{\myblockwidth}
\newcounter{boxcounter}

\newlength{\mylinewidths}
\newlength{\myinnersep}
\setlength{\mylinewidths}{5pt}
\setlength{\myinnersep}{2ex}

\NewEnviron{mycolorblock}[2][]{%
  \addtocounter{boxcounter}{1}%
  \setlength{\myblockwidth}{#2}%
  \addtolength{\myblockwidth}{-4ex}%
  \contourlength{.333pt}%
  \node[
  #1,
  draw=orange,
  fill=orange!10,
  line width=\mylinewidths,
  inner sep=2ex,
  rounded corners = 2.5ex,
  path picture={%
    \node[white,
    circle, draw=blue!20, line width=\mylinewidths, inner sep=.1pt,
    scale = 15,
    font=\bf] at (path picture bounding box.center)
    {\contour{blue!20}{\the\value{boxcounter}}};}
  ](box\the\value{boxcounter}){
    \begin{minipage}[t][]{\myblockwidth}%
      \BODY
    \end{minipage}%
  };
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,node distance=5pt]
  \begin{mycolorblock}{\textwidth}
    \blindtext[2]
  \end{mycolorblock}
  \begin{mycolorblock}[below = of box1]{\textwidth}
    \blindtext[2]
  \end{mycolorblock}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Process with `pdflatex` the background number for the second block (and any additional is off-center:
[image: result of example]
The background is thereby always shifted away from the center of the first block and the distance from the center of its block seems to be scaled by `scale`.

I am not even sure it's the `positioning` library which causes this behavior. If someone could point out how to fix or migrate this issue, I would by grateful.

Comment: The node in the `path picture` is probably inheriting `below = of box1`. Does putting `anchor=center` in the path picture node help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `positioning` option `below=...` changes the anchor of the box (the outer  node) to `north`. The `path picture` node is an inner node and therefore it inherits this anchor.

Adding `anchor=center` to the options of the node inside the `path picture` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\usepackage{environ}

\newlength{\myblockwidth}
\newcounter{boxcounter}

\newlength{\mylinewidths}
\newlength{\myinnersep}
\setlength{\mylinewidths}{5pt}
\setlength{\myinnersep}{2ex}

\NewEnviron{mycolorblock}[2][]{%
  \addtocounter{boxcounter}{1}%
  \setlength{\myblockwidth}{#2}%
  \addtolength{\myblockwidth}{-4ex}%
  \contourlength{.333pt}%
  \node[
  #1,
  draw=orange,
  fill=orange!10,
  line width=\mylinewidths,
  inner sep=2ex,
  rounded corners = 2.5ex,
  path picture={%
    \node[white,
    circle, draw=blue!20, line width=\mylinewidths, inner sep=.1pt,
    scale = 15,
    font=\bf,
    anchor=center % set the anchor of the node inside the path picture
    ] at (path picture bounding box.center)
    {\contour{blue!20}{\the\value{boxcounter}}};}
  ](box\the\value{boxcounter}){
    \begin{minipage}{\myblockwidth}%
      \BODY
    \end{minipage}%
  };
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,node distance=5pt]
  \begin{mycolorblock}{\textwidth}
    \blindtext[2]
  \end{mycolorblock}
  \begin{mycolorblock}[below = of box1]{\textwidth}
    \blindtext[2]
  \end{mycolorblock}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer to your question but another way of producing this kind of numbered boxes with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

`tcolorbox` includes a `watermark` option to include watermarks into boxes background. You can have `text`, `image` and `tikz` watermarks.

Another option which can simplify a little bit your works is its automatic counter handling. You can create a `\newcounter` in preamble and option `[use counter=yournewcounter]` automatically increases the counter which every new `tcolorbox`. Even more, you don't need to remember which counter is used, because inside `tcolorbox` declaration the counter value is just `\thetcbcounter`.

Next is a code example defining boxes similar to your ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\newlength{\myblockwidth}
\newlength{\mylinewidths}
\newlength{\myinnersep}
\setlength{\mylinewidths}{5pt}
\setlength{\myinnersep}{2ex}
\contourlength{.333pt}

\newcounter{boxcounter}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=boxcounter]{mycolorblock}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    notitle,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=orange!10,
    watermark tikz={\node[circle, text=white, draw=blue!20,%
            line width=\mylinewidths, inner sep=.1pt, scale=15,
            font=\bfseries] {\contour{blue!20}{\textcolor{white}{\thetcbcounter}}};},%
      watermark color=white,
      width=#2,
      boxrule=\mylinewidths,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mycolorblock}{\textwidth}
\thetcbcounter \blindtext[2]
\end{mycolorblock}
\par
\begin{mycolorblock}{\textwidth}
\thetcbcounter \blindtext[2]
\end{mycolorblock}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update*

`tcolorbox` includes `remember as` option which assigns a name to the box. This name can be used as a reference in external `tikzpictures`. Therefore is possible to draw conecting arrows between several `tcolorboxes`. Next code shows an example.

Now boxes have three parameters. The first one which is optional, will be passed as extra `tcolorbox` options to `mycolorblock`. The second one (mandatory) is the watermark number and the third (also mandatory) is the box width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin={1cm,2cm,1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{multirow}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newlength{\myblockwidth}
\newlength{\mylinewidths}
\newlength{\myinnersep}
\setlength{\mylinewidths}{5pt}
\setlength{\myinnersep}{2ex}
\contourlength{.333pt}

\newcounter{boxcounter}

\newtcolorbox{mycolorblock}[3][]{%
    enhanced, 
      nobeforeafter,
    notitle,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=orange!10,
    watermark tikz={\node[circle, text=white, draw=blue!20,%
            line width=\mylinewidths, inner sep=.1pt, scale=15,
            font=\bfseries] {\contour{blue!20}{\textcolor{white}{#2}}};},%
      watermark color=white,
      width=#3,
      boxrule=\mylinewidths,
      remember as ={#2}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{mycolorblock}{1}{.45\textwidth}
\blindtext[1]
\end{mycolorblock} & 
\begin{mycolorblock}{2}{.45\textwidth}
\blindtext[1]
\end{mycolorblock} \\
\begin{mycolorblock}{3}{.45\textwidth}
\blindtext[1]
\end{mycolorblock}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, line width=\mylinewidths, draw=orange]
\draw[->] (1.north) --++(90:.75cm) -| (2);
\draw[->] (1.west) --++(180:.75cm) |- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -| (2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice package. I will use these boxes on a poster to connect them e.g. with arrows.  Does the `tcolorbox` also allow to position boxes relative to each other or would I still need to put them in tikz-nodes for this actions? [Example](http://imgur.com/Qmt5yLh)

Comment: @Hasenblut. You can use `remember as` options. It's shown in updated answer.